# How do I find a character in the middle of a word/line

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I am looking for the `@` character, in strings like:

```
@test@example
hello@there
myemail@gmail.com
```

I would like to only match the `@` if it is not at the beginning or end of the line, i.e. do not match the first `@` in this example.

How do I do this?

Comment: language you are using?

Comment: I am using sublime text

Answer (score 3):

If the language you are using supports `lookahead` and `lookbehind` then, you can use

```
(?<=.)@(?=.)
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?<=.) #Assure that there is at least one character present before @
@ #Match @
(?=.) #Assure that there is at least one character present after @
```

or

```
(?<!^)@(?!$)
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?<!^) #Assure that @ do not follows starting of string
@ #Match @
(?!$) #Assure that @ is not followed by end of string
```

Comment: thanks, works great. what's the difference between the two?

Comment: @Alex, first one is positive lookaroud and the last is negative. Like before and after should be some character, or before and after ahould not be start and end of the string.

Comment: Just fyi `(?!^)@` would do the same as `(?<!^)@` no need for lookbehind.

Comment: I see same result (:

Comment: @bobblebubble yeah `m` flag was not enabled

Comment: I don't see a different behaviour in both variants in multiline [`(?!^)@(?!$)`](https://regex101.com/r/tD2lK0/1) vs [`(?<!^)@(?!$)`](https://regex101.com/r/yQ7gA2/1). Just interesting to mention if someone wants to use your pattern with eg JS.

Comment: @bobblebubble you are right..i said that in previous comment..i was using only `g` and not `gm`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simply use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
\b@\b
```

This matches `@` if there is a word bordering to the left and a word bordering to the right.

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lC2hE6/1)

Comment: i think OP is trying to match email..so this won't match valid email like `@test+@example`

Comment: if its not email then also it won't match

Comment: @rock321987 Was just my thought for a character bordering to word characters. Sure depends.

Comment: yup..that totally depends on input

Comment: I don't understand, it seems to work perfectly for the examples supplied.

Comment: @Alex It always works when word charcters `[A-Za-z0-9_]` are bordering to the character. That's how I understood your question. It does not work for such as `&@a` because the left character `&` is not a word character.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to match the whole line or @'s only, but try this one :

```
\b[@]
```